# restructuring class library and remove console writelines

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class library its pretty small and simple.

It is used by console applications. The library has a few lines of code where it writes to the console (which I now realise was poor design on my behalf).

Also I have a WPF application that I would like to make use of this class library.

I was thinking that maybe I should remove the lines where it writes to the console but raise an event that returns a string instead. So the console application that use this library can either listen to the event & output the string or do nothing. This would also enable me to use it with my WPF application.

I have two questions.

1) Is my idea wise or is there a better way?

2) Say I have 5 classes & that in each one there is a Console.WriteLine. Would I have to make an event in each class? Or would it be wise to create a base class and inherit the event? I do have one class that already inherits from another class so this wouldn't work

Comment: Hard to say without concrete examples.  The _typical_ way is to have methods that take in input and return the output.  events are usually used when the return is non-deterministic (i.e. the return will happen at some point in time that you don't control, like getting a result form an asynchronous call)

Comment: you could use a callback function that would work similar to an event, but it would be executed immediately, not `at some point in time`.  if it's null, your classes do nothing. If it's not null, execute it.  The main app (console or wpf, e.g.) would have to implement the callback and pass it in.

Comment: It depends on the use, but your classes could take an ILogger interface, and then where you instantiate them, you could pass in a ConsoleLogger, or any other kind of logger.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a callback-construct such as this. I'm not sure why and when this may be too dirty, but I found it handy enough in some situations to have a default behaviour that can be easily redirected

```
class Box
{
    public static Action<String> Echo { get; set; }
    static Box() { Echo = (String s) => {Console.WriteLine(s);};}

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Box.Echo.Invoke(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

...

```
        Box obj = new Box();
        obj.DoSomething();
        Box.Echo = (String s) => { MessageBox.Show(s); };
        obj.DoSomething();
```